# Specificity in MAPK/ERK pathway and PC12 Cells

Tags: cell-signaling

**Background**

PC12 Cell stimulation leads to distinct outcomes upon stimulation with either EGF or NGF (epidermal and nerve growth factors). The outputs are transmitted through the MAPK/ERK signaling pathway; stimulation with EGF causes transient activation of the ERK, via a negative feedback loop, leading to cell proliferation whereas stimulation with NGF leads to sustained activation of ERK, via a positive feedback loop, leading to differentiation.

**Question**

How does the signaling pathway know which kind of feedback loop to initiate at the ERK level from upstream stimulation by EGF or NGF?

**Helpful Image to explain question**

To reiterate: I want to figure out how EGF binding at the membrane level triggers negative feedback downstream, and NGF binding triggers positive feedback?

A link to the image is (http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v12/n2/fig_tab/nrm3048_F4.html)

[image]